# Empty Plot Error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

When I run the code,

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 0.01;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] :=  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2];

mem : γ[τ_] :=  mem = NIntegrate[
  integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

oldprob[nx_, ny_, nz_, τ_] := 1/2 (1 + nz^2 + Exp[-γ[τ] ]*(nx^2 + ny^2));

newprob[nx_, ny_, nz_, τ_] := 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[nz^2 + Exp[-γ[τ] ]^2 * (nx^2 + ny^2) ]);

Plot[{oldprob[1/Sqrt (2), 1/Sqrt (2), 0, τ], 
 newprob[1/Sqrt (2), 1/Sqrt (2), 0, τ]}, {τ, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 15],
```

I get an empty plot as the output. What could be the error?

Comment: `Sqrt[2]` not `Sqrt (2)`

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake when calling `Sqrt[]` function within `Plot[]` function. You've used round-brackets `()` instead of square-brackets `[]`

### Example

```
Plot[
{
oldprob[1/Sqrt [2],1/Sqrt [2],0,τ],
newprob[1/Sqrt [2],1/Sqrt [2],0,τ]
},
{τ,0,2},
PlotRange->{0,1},MaxRecursion->10,WorkingPrecision->15
]
```

### Output

[image: out]

Comment: @m_goldberg, thank you for editing this post! I had no idea how to get symbols to show properly when copy-pasting from Mathematica IDE

Comment: have a look [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor), quite cool.